# How to migrate all collections in tfs2017 to vsts into a single vsts account

Tags: azure-devops

I am having a hard time migrating a tfs2017 update 1 to vsts. I am using microsoft's migration guide however I have managed to migrate a single collection and its users and team account into a vsts account (Dry run), but the issue is I cannot seem to find a way to migrate all the other collections into into that particular account, does anyone have faced situation like this or am I doing something wrong here, Or Is it possible or not, if yes then please throw some light on the possibility.

Comment: What's the result after merging collection via OpsHub tool? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility

Answer (score 0):

You can't. VSTS only supports one collection per account.

Your options are as follows:

1. Combine your existing collections into a single collection, then migrate that collection. This may be more or less difficult depending on the amount of data and history you have, and what amount of that you need to retain, and the fidelity at which you wish to retain it.
2. There is a concept called [Organizations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/11/how-we-plan-to-enable-creating-multiple-collections-per-account/) that will allow multiple VSTS accounts to be managed underneath a single umbrella, but it's still in preview. 
   Per the [feature timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/news/features-timeline), it's slated for third quarter 2017, so sometime this fall.

Comment: how can I move all the collections into a single collection can you providE any source where I can read about this..?

Comment: You have to rely on third-party tools to migrate work item and source control history. The fidelity isn't perfect. There's the TFS integration platform, which is no longer maintained but probably still works, and a selection of tools from OpsHub.